# Poll a specific folder for files starting with "Abc" once found send an email stating it's appeared and when

Tags: email, directory, polling

Firstly I'll state, I'm shocking when it comes to nearly all form of scripting, so any tips/help will be greatly appreciated! I was looking to do this task via batch file but from researching here on the forums it looks like a vbscript is the only way to do it.

I'm looking to schedule a task that looks on a mapped network drive... Polls the folder for new files, but only new files that start with "Abc...." when the files arrive, I'd like an email to be sent to a certain address with simple text stating the file has arrived and the time it arrived. That's pretty much it.

A log file of the information above stored would be useful but asking for that would be pushing my luck..

Thanks
Darren

Comment: You question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  What OS are you using?  What email system are you using?  You see too broad.  In fact thinking about it you might get a better response on User Super than SO.

Comment: Os is windows, email would be using an SMTP server